# Why is one baseboard heating hotter, and not controlled by thermostat

Tags: plumbing, heating

We have a 3 unit house with hot water baseboard heat fired by an oil boiler. Apt 1 has her thermostat set at 70 but her room temperature is 82 so she set thermostat to 50 and the living room baseboard is hot, and not being controlled by thermostat.  All other baseboards in the apartment are working normally as are all baseboards in apts 2 and 3. We changed her thermostat but baseboard is still heating too much. Any ideas on what to check??

Comment: Did you check the valves controlled by the thermostat?  There really should be a thermostat controlling the living room heater or it could be controlled by the one in the other room with a stuck valve.

Comment: The thermostat in the living room controls the entire apartment, that's why we were puzzled as to why just the living room baseboard is not responding to the thermostat being turned down.

Comment: You need to check for a faulty valve that's not closing properly.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the baseboard in question is circulating by thermo-syphon with the circulator pump not running. Hot fluid rises from the boiler and cold fluid falls from the baseboard unit resulting in circulation without a call for heat - common in the one closest above the boiler or with the least complex piping path.

Adding a check valve or even a "trap" to the piping loop can stop that - something to ensure that the pump needs to run for fluid to flow in the loop.

If you have a system with zone valves and one pump rather than a pump per loop it might be a zone valve failure.

Answer (score 0):

Being a 3 unit house you would have to verify the hydronic piping and which zones are which, going to which baseboards, controlled by which thermostats.  And then verify how the piping is zoned off, that all zone valves and check valves are functioning.  From the sound of it it could be **ghost flow**.

you would get a good answer asking this on **The Wall** at **heatinghelp.com**. They will know all the correct terminology and tell u what specifically to look for.